# How to create a gradient box shadow with transparent background?

Tags: html, css

I want to make div with gradient box shadow. And I have found how to do with :before and blur effect...
But I want to make div with transparent background. For example

```
div{
height:200px;
width:200px;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3)

}
div::before{
content:'';
z-index: -1;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
filter: blur(10px)
}
```

Is it some way to make the before element invisible in place where is the main element?

Comment: `Position: abosolute;` and `Contact:"";` are incorrect. It should be `position: absolute; content: ''`

Answer (score 1):

You can try `clip-path` and easily get the code from my online generator: https://css-generators.com/gradient-shadows/

```css
.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
}

.box::before {
  --d: -20px; /* bigger than the value of the blur with negative sign*/
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  inset:0;
  background: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
  filter: blur(10px);
  clip-path: polygon(var(--d) var(--d),calc(100% - var(--d)) var(--d),calc(100% - var(--d)) calc(100% - var(--d)),var(--d) calc(100% - var(--d)),var(--d) var(--d),0 0,0 100%,100% 100%,100% 0,0 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this...

```css
  div {
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
        position: relative;
      }
      div::before {
        content: "";
        z-index: -1;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
        filter: blur(10px);
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i do whant to make the blurry part invisible in the place where is the box, i need to make it visible only in space around

Comment: just decrease your blur to 4px then you will have blur around box

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
Position: abosolute; and Contact:""; to position: absolute; content: ''
```

and add this to your div

```
    div{
    position:relative; 
}
```

Comment: [Like this ?](https://imgur.com/QloaVGY)